# Show underline in anchor if having href using css

Tags: css

Show underline in anchor if having href using css

```
<a class="myLink" >click here</a>
```

show underline on hover

```
<a class="myLink" href="http:\\whatever.com">click here</a>
```

should not show underline on hover

what should i write in myLink css which work for both.

Comment: so you want underline if there isn't a href, and don't show underline if there is href?

Comment: Also, if it doesn't have an href...it's not a link.

Comment: He is doing something with his own idea.we dont want to know what it was?.just answer his question if it is poossible frnd..

Answer (score 3):

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}    

a[href]
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ar06ej/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CSS Attribute Selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a[href] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Anchor with href set</a>
<br />
<a>Anchor without href</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a css like..

```
<Style>
    a {
       text-decoration: none;
        }
     a[href] {
         text-decoration: underline;
       }
   </Style>
```

Remember this will affect the entire anchor tag on your web page.you will give a specific id so as to Avoid this conflict

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtpsp2c4/1/) code for some extra.